# ZSH thinks unterminated quote if preceded by exclamation mark (!)

Tags: zsh

I have zsh 5.3 (through oh-my-zsh), if I run `echo --message="foo!"`, I get unterminated quote prompt on the next line:

```
$ echo --message="foo!"
dquote>
```

This doesn' happen in bash.

When I drop the `!` character from the argument, it works fine:

```
$ echo --message="foo"
--message=foo
```

What’s happening here?

---

I should also note that if I answer the unterminated quote prompt with `"` and hit return, I get this output, which totally drops the `!`:

```
$ echo --message="foo!"
dquote> "
--message=foo
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's the history expansion at work.

This is what the `zshexpn(1)` manpage says about it:

> If the shell encounters the character sequence `!"` in the  input,  the
>          history  mechanism  is temporarily disabled until the current list (see
>          `zshmisc(1)`) is fully parsed.  The `!"` is removed from the  input,  and
>          any subsequent `!` characters have no special significance.

Comment: So as either escape `"foo\!"` or use single quotes `'foo!'`. Or even `"foo!"!"`, `!" "foo!"`, etc..

Comment: What is it expanding?  The manpage makes it sound like `!"` is a special token that disables "the history mechanism", which I assume means it prevents the current line from appearing in the previous command list/history buffer?  Wouldn't that be more like 'history compression (or perhaps, _excision_)'?

Comment: "history expansion" is the official name of this `!` feature -- you call it "csh bangs" if you like. And `!"` does no more than told in that paragraph; in particular, it does **not** prevent the current line from being pushed in the history -- why should it?

Comment: How can one disable this dangerous (and quite useless to me I might add) abomination?

Comment: @yPhil afaik the only thing you can do is disable the history expansion completely with `set -K` or `setopt nobanghist`.\

Comment: @mosvy that did it, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I couldn't figure out what `!"` does, except frustrate otherwise simple expressions, but eventually found out: if `!"` appears in a line, anywhere, it is removed and all `!` expressions afterwards on the same line don't trigger history expansion. Eg. `l!"s [!a-g]est.txt` is equivalent to `ls [!a-g]est.txt` except the `!` has its normal negation behaviour.